# Freeze on close terminal

Tags: nvidia, gui, virtual-console

Consider the following steps.

1. I ctrl-alt-f5 into a terminal.
2. I log in.
3. I hit ctrl-d, or `exit`, to exit the terminal.
4. My screen shows the graphical login page.  (This is unexpected.)
5. Neither the mouse nor the keyboard affect the screen, despite that I can see the mouse in the bottom right corner.
6. If I ctrl-alt-f6 into another terminal, the screen does not change.  I still see a frozen GUI.  However, I can blindly log into the shell as if I were in a virtual terminal, and do shell stuff like turn on my keyboard lights (echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/ blah blah blah) or reboot my computer.
   6.1. I have not tried logging into the original frozen terminal.  I'd sooner ask the question without, than lock up my computer yet again.
7. However, if I ctrl-alt-f1 back to what should be the actual GUI, the screen goes black, and nothing does anything, anymore.
   7.1. For instance, I can no longer blindly log in, and caps lock no longer toggles the keyboard light.
   7.2. However, REISUB still (judging by hdd lights) unmounts drives and reboots.  No screen changes, though, until reboot occurs.  I think the first time this happened, though, REISUB did *not* work, but I'm not sure.

Any idea what's wrong, or how to unfreeze things?  I did recently install an NVIDIA driver, to fix my aspect ratio and frame rate.  GeForce GTX 1080.